# Is there a limitation on how many paths Next.js can prerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am attempting to pre-render 2000+ pages for all company ticker symbols in the code below:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

    //fetch all company symbols available in this financialmodelingprep API (> 2000)
    const res = await fetch(
        "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/list?apikey=asecret"
    );
    const AllCompanies = await res.json();

    //reduce array to observe that smaller arrays prerender more successfully 
    const paths = AllCompanies.slice(0, 600).map((ticker) => {
        return {
            params: { id: ticker.symbol },
        };
    });

    return {
        paths, 
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    
    //fetch company news data based on getStaticPaths params
    const res = await fetch(
        `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock_news?tickers=${context.params.id}&limit=50&apikey=asecret`
    );
    const newsData = await res.json();
    return {
        props: { newsData: newsData },
    };
}

const CompanyPage = ({ newsData }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>{newsData[0].symbol}</div>
            <div>{newsData[0].publishedDate}</div>
            <div>{newsData[0].title}</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default CompanyPage;
```

Where the getStaticPaths' API response format is:

```
[
{
"symbol": "SPY",
"name": "SPDR S&P 500 ETF Trust",
"price": 422.6,
"exchange": "New York Stock Exchange Arca"
},
{
"symbol": "CMCSA",
"name": "Comcast Corporation",
"price": 57,
"exchange": "Nasdaq Global Select"
},
...
]
```

The error I get is always similar to:

```
[=== ] info  - Generating static pages (453/604)
Error occurred prerendering page "/company/TOPS". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error        
TypeError: Cannot read property 'symbol' of undefined
    at CompanyPage (C:\Users\Jake Arsement\rps\simple-markets-next\.next\server\pages\company\[id].js:54:29)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /company/MON
        /company/TOPS
        /company/WY

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! simple-markets-next@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Where failing paths vary each time I execute 'npm run build'.

It seems like Next is having trouble with the amount of paths when above ~300, as I've checked to ensure there is a 'symbol' property for the failing paths. I'm wondering if there is some path array size limitation. I could not find any mention of a limit in the docs. Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the API requests for those paths are returning the expected response? Could there be a request limit issue with the API?

Comment: @juliomalves I'll check the API responses again. It seems like Next may not be able to handle the volume given that different pages will fail every build when the API response is the same. But yeah let me check the exact API response instance opposed to the API response in general.

Comment: There is most likely a problem with API responses that's causing your issue. 2000 prerendered paths isn't a lot for NextJS.